# What type is a sklearn model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm writing some code which evaluates different sklearn models against some data. I am using type hints, both for my own education and to help other people who will eventually have to read my code.

My question is how do I specify the type of a sklearn predictor (such as `LinearRegression()`)?

For example:

```
def model_tester(model : Predictor,
                 parameter: int
                 ) -> np.ndarray:
     """An example function with type hints."""

     # do stuff to model 

     return values
```

I see the [typing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) can make  new types or I can use `TypeVar` to do:

```
Predictor = TypeVar('Predictor')
```

but I wouldn't want to use this if there was already a conventional type for an sklearn model.

Checking the type of LinearRegression() yields:

```
 sklearn.linear_model.base.LinearRegression
```

and this is clearly of use, but only if I am interested in the LinearRegression model.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the most generic class that all models inherit from would be `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator`.

If you want to be more specific, maybe use `sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin` or `sklearn.base.RegressorMixin`.

So I would do:

```
from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin


def model_tester(model: RegressorMixin, parameter: int) -> np.ndarray:
     """An example function with type hints."""

     # do stuff to model 

     return values
```

I am no expert in type checking, so correct me if this is not right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both BaseEstimator and ClassifierMixin. But when I call self.estimator.fit, my IDE (Pycharm) complains that it cannot find the "fit" attribute. And it is right. Those classes don't implement fit. it is implemented separately for each estimator (e.g. LogisticRegression).
Does anyone know what is the correct type hint for an argument that is supposed to take a scikit-learn estimator?

Answer (score 30):

From Python 3.8 on (or earlier using [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/)), you can use `typing.Protocol`. Using protocols, you can use a concept called [structural subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) to define exactly the type's expected structure:

```
from typing import Protocol
# from typing_extensions import Protocol  # for Python <3.8

class ScikitModel(Protocol):
    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None): ...
    def predict(self, X): ...
    def score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None): ...
    def set_params(self, **params): ...
```

which you can then use as a type hint:

```
def do_stuff(model: ScikitModel) -> Any:
    model.fit(train_data, train_labels)  # this type checks 
    score = model.score(test_data, test_labels)  # this type checks
    ...
```

Answer (score 12):

A good work around is to create your own custom type hint class (using Union) that includes all the models you commonly use. It requires more effort but allows you to be specific and works with PyCharm.

```
ModelRegressor = Union[LinearRegression, DecisionTreeRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, SVR]

def foo(model: ModelRegressor):
    do_something
```

Answer (score 8):

You can set type as `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` everywhere. This may be a solution without creating additional entities.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a good workaround. I needed code completion for sklearn predictors, so wanted to use type hints.